# Prevent keypress when Alt key plus number from Bloq number is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric, keydown

I'm having problems avoiding the special chars (Alt + number from Bloq. num -> ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○)in an input.

My input is declared like this:

```
<html:text styleId="inputMaxVol" styleClass="numeric"/>
```

This is on my onReady

```
$(".numeric").keydown(function(event) {
    return maskNumber();
});
```

And here is where I'm trying to do the job (with no success)

```
function maskNumber() {
   if (event) {
     var charCode = (event.which)? event.which : event.keyCode;
     console.log(charCode);
     // If not a number
     if ((charCode < 47 || charCode > 58) && (charCode < 95 || charCode > 105))  {
        console.log("not a number");
        return false;
     } else if (event.altKey) {
        //No special characters admitted
        console.log("Alt pressed");
        return false;
     }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If I press Alt + 1 (key "1" from the numeric pad) the white smiley face appears and in my log appears something like that

```
18
not a number
97
Alt pressed
```

I've tried too with the event.preventDefault() with no success. Any idea about where is my problem?

Thanks, I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**UPDATE:** As explained in comments the solution comes changing the keydown event for keypress and changing the charcode comparation numbers (Now is only if (`charCode < 48 || charCode > 57`) due to the numbers returned have changed too.

So the solution is as follows

```
$(".numeric").keypress(function(event) {
    return maskNumber();
});

function maskNumber() {
   if (event) {
      var charCode = (event.which)? event.which : event.keyCode;        
      // If not a number
      if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) {                     
           return false;
      }              
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Simple as that!

Comment: try this library : https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 4):

> Try below code it will work on each browser or if you want to use library then visit this link: https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys

```js
$("#txtmy").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which.toString().length > 3)  {   
     event.preventDefault();
     return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtmy"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Returning false will not disable the event.
You need to do an `event.preventDefault()`, which stops the event from happening, instead of returning false.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

The `return false` is working for an `onbeforesubmit` event, of a Form.

Comment: As you can see in my first post, I already tried that but the character is displayed too :(

Comment: Did you add the `event.preventDefault()` inside the `onkeydown` ?

$(".numeric").keydown(function(event) {
    if(!maskNumber()) {
        event .preventDefault();
    }
});

Comment: Yes, even with only `$(".numeric").keydown(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });` any character is typed except the special ones with Alt key [☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○]

Comment: Please check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/piakovakis/ws89s5rL/1/
By pressing a number from the NumPad, while the ALT key pressed, the preventDefault, stops the addition of the pressed character.

Comment: Sorry, but is not working for me... Maybe is because we're using different navigators? I'm testing this jsfiddle with Chrome Versión 59.0.3071.115 and IE 11.0.9600. Look at this https://postimg.org/image/jbaj08uh7/ @p-iakovakis

Comment: It was working on me because of the different OS. I tested it in a Windows evnironment and found a solution. You need to change the event `keydown` to `keypress` https://jsfiddle.net/piakovakis/ws89s5rL/2/

Comment: Changing keydown for keypress is the key... Now there are some charcters that can be written now (and not before!) If you type the following keys are written: abcdefghi (Tried here: jsfiddle.net/piakovakis/ws89s5rL/2) I only have to change the charcode tested because as I can see the charcode is not the same with the event keydown (66) and with the keypress (97). Thanks!

Comment: If you could update (edit) your question with the answer, so that others can find it easily, would be great.